# Computation PEV with Sommer in Genomic prediction context - Plant Breeding Hybrids

Tags: r, prediction

I have a small question about PEVs for genomic selection results output on hybrids plant with Sommer R packages.

I have a model with 3 kinships (2 parental kinships and kronecker of 2 parents)
Y~ GCA1 + GCA2 + SCA

For the blup and the heritability, it's good but for the PEVs, I don't know the most fair strategy.

Here, I obtain 1 PEV for each factor so 3 PEVs ==> Each PEV is obtain by sqrt(diag(ans$PEV.u.hat$GCA1))  -  sqrt(diag(ans$PEV.u.hat$GCA2)) -  sqrt(diag(ans$PEV.u.hat$SCA))

how can I get the real PEV of each of my hybrids (GCA1+GCA2+SCA) ?

Comment: *"small question about PEVs for genomic selection results output on hybrids plant with Sommer R packages"* This is way too domain specific and not a good question for SO. If you can turn this into a domain-agnostic but specific coding question, please edit your post accordingly. Otherwise I suggest removing and posting on e.g. the Bioinformatics stack (or SeqAnswers or Biostars).

Comment: Hello, please also add some relevant sample data with `dput(head(df))`.